# Twilio Verification CustomerFriendlyName fails

Tags: twilio, sms-verification

I want to verify a phone-number in Twilio by sending a link with parameters.The value of the last parameter is the code Twilio Verification object generates.
I've created a service with a simple friendly name.
But the link I want to send to the user, must be made for each verification:
So I've tried to use the method .setCustomFriendlyName(link),
but I get: Invalid parameter: FriendlyName. It has 45 characters.
So I replaced the link with "Test".
Then I get: Custom friendly name not allowed.
I'm not able to find relevant information about this in the docs, or anywhere else ...
Could someone help, please ?

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.Verification;

public class TwilioAdministration {

public static final String TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = "ACxxxxx";
public static final String TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxx";
public static final String TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE = "VAxxxxx";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Twilio.init(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
        String verifyUrl = "https://aaaaa.shortcm.li/AlQvb71=I&2=24&3=";

        Verification.creator(TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE,"+nnnnnnnnn",
                "sms").setCustomFriendlyName(verifyUrl).create();

    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is the version of my SDK: 7.55.0 (com.twilio.sdk)

Answer (score 1):

I saw somewhere that only numbers that was going to send sms, needed to be verified. My numbers are only receivers. So I rather checked the numbers with lookup and tested the type returned. Problem solved.